# Check words in multi files, if the same then replace by space

Tags: python

In test01.txt

```
are
lol
test
hello
next
```

In text02.txt

```
lol : positive
next : objective
sunday! : objective
are : objective
you : objective
going? : neutral
mail : objective
```

My codes:

```
file1 = open('C://Users/Desktop/test01.txt')
file2 = open('C://Users/Desktop/test02.txt')

rfile1 = file1.readlines()
rfile2 = file2.read()

for test2 in rfile2.split("\n"):
    testt2 = test2.split("\t")
    for test1 in rfile1:
        slsw1 = test1.split()
        for wttest2 in testt2:
            sttestt2 = wttest2.split(" ")
        if sttestt2[0] in slsw1[0]:
            sttestt2[0] = sttestt2[0].replace(sttestt2[0], "")
            print sttestt2[0], ":", sttestt2[2]
```

Expected results:

```
 : positive
 : objective
sunday! : objective
 : objective
you : objective
going? : neutral
mail : objective
```

I am trying to replace the same word in "test02.txt" with space and print out for seeing the results but I got print out only space. I want to print out all results as in expected results.

Did I miss something? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Create a set of all the records from the first file
lookup = set(open("test01.txt").read().splitlines())
#and then open the second file for reading and a new out file
#for writing
with open("test02.txt") as fin, open("test02.out","w") as fout:
    #iterate through each line in the file
    for line in fin:
        #and split it with the seperator
        line  = map(str.strip, line.split(":"))
        #if the key is in the lookup set 
        if line[0] in lookup:
            #replace it with space
            line[0] = " "
        #and then join the line tuple and suffix with newline
        line = ":".join(line) + "\n"
        #finally write the resultant line to the out file
        fout.write(line)
```

Comment: Not trying to be offensive or anything, but just wondering, how was this better answer than mine? O.o

Comment: @Mahi: Consider the overhead of searching the entire file content for each line in the first file.

Comment: @Abhijit So you rather create a map for each line and use `.join()`'s and write the lines one by one? I'm 90% sure that my method is faster, and it should be much easier to understand too.

Comment: @ThanaDaray if you're really trying to understand python, you should make sure you understand both of our answers perfectly, and choose the better way.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Open test02.txt in read mode
with open("C:/Users/Desktop/test02.txt", "r") as infile:
    # Read the content of the file
    content = infile.read()

# Open test01.txt in read mode
with open("C:/Users/Desktop/test01.txt", "r") as infile:
    # Loop through every line in the file
    for line in file:
        # Get the word from the line
        word = line.strip()
        # Replace "word :" with " :" from test02.txt content
        content.replace("%s :"%word, " :")

# Open test02.txt in write mode
with open("C:/Users/Desktop/test02.txt", "w") as outfile:
    # Write the new, replaced content
    outfile.write(content)
```

Also you should really consider learning some better naming methods. `rfile` really doesn't tell anything, other than that it's related to the file. I'd rather use `file_content` or `file_lines` or so.

Also: `test2, testt2, test1, slsw1, wttest2, sttestt2` ... What?

Try naming your varibles so that the name tells what the variable is used for, it will be much easier for yourself, and for us. :)